# How do I observe an object's state until all properties are updated?

Tags: c#

Let's assume I have a class like this:

```
public class Foo
{
    public int X;
    public int Y;
}
```

And I have two methods which operate on a Foo object as such:

```
public void ModifyXandY()
{
    foo.X = 2;
    ModifyY();
}

public void ModifyY()
{
    foo.Y = 1;
}
```

Now, I want to be notified when there is an update to the values of X or Y and I know that I can do that by implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface, but the issue is I need to get the last state of the object. So, if I call `ModifyXandY()` I would be notified when X is set to 2, but I would get a Foo object with X=2 and Y=0, but I want to be notified when Y is set to 1, so that I would get a Foo object with X=2 and Y=1. On the other hand, if I call `ModifyY()` I need to be notified immediately, because there won't be any other changes to Foo object.

How would one implement such an observer?

Comment: Out of curiousity, why would you need this?

Comment: You are doing something outside `Foo` which `Foo` has no way of knowing. Either put the modifying methods inside `Foo` (then you can use an event) or get notified outside of `Foo` (where the action takes place).

Comment: You seem to be doing something complicated that would be a better fit for immutable objects and/or a builder and/or a command pattern for updates. If you want explicit observation over how and when an object's state changes, better make the changes themselves explicit.

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev I need to make sure that property observers get the consistent Foo object state because those observers send data to analytics servers, and I need the code to send as less events as possible with a consistent state. I know that there might be better solutions, but this is the task at hand for the moment.

Answer (score 0):

**Not-so-good idea: make your notifications only when *state is consistent***

If you're implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged`, you could only raise the events once your object is in a consistent state:

```cs
public class Foo : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public int X { get; private set; } // No PropertyChanged event here
    public int Y { get; private set; } // No PropertyChanged event here

    public void ModifyXandY()
    {
        foo.X = 2;
        ModifyYPrivate();
        // State is now consistent
        RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(X));
        RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(Y));
    }

    public void ModifyY()
    {
        ModifyYPrivate();
        RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(Y));
    }

    private void ModifyYPrivate()
    {
        foo.Y = 1;
    }

    #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
    #endregion
}
```

This appears a bit risky because you might still privately change `X` or `Y and forget to raise the events.

**Better idea: *make your state always consistent* and don't bother about change notifications**

You could change the above code to make the idea of *consistency* a key principle in your `Foo` class by making part of its state *immutable*.

The key is *making changes to the `Foo` class consistent right from the start, instead of wondering when to notify of state changes.*

You could change its couple of properties `X` and `Y` to an immutable `struct` holding both `X` and `Y`:

```cs
public readonly struct ConsistentXY
{
    public readonly double X;
    public readonly double Y;

    public Point(double x, double y) => (X, Y) = (x, y);
}
```

And then you could implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` in a normal way.

```cs
public class Foo : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private ConsistentXY _state;

    public ConsistentXY State
    {
        get => _state;
        set
        {
            _state = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(State));
        }
    }

    public int X => State.X;
    public int Y => State.Y;

    public void ModifyXandY()
    {
        State = new ConsistentXY(2, 1);
    }

    #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members
    /* ...same code... */
    #endregion
}
```

That would force you to change some code to ensure that all modifications you make to `State` are consistent but that's pretty legit to ensure consistency of state.